# Stop static constructor

Tags: .net, static, constructor

How to stop a static constructor(i.e. module constructor & type constructor) from running in .NET?

For example:

```
class A  
{  
    static A()  
    {  
        Environment.Exit(0);  
    }  
    static int i()  
    {  
        return 100;
    }  
}
```

How to invoke `i()` without exiting?

Comment: //Environment.Exit(0); :)

Comment: @kofucii: LOL for the "comment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually i am making a interpreter of .net,

If you use

```
  System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName);
```

The static ctor won't run.

Comment: Yes, i know the static constructor will not run in reflection only context, but i will not be able to create objects of type in assembly  too.

Comment: @Kii, and dotNET's type-safety says you can't create objects w/o running the associated static ctors.

Comment: That means you will have to build your own CLR...  good luck.

Answer (score 5):

> How to stop a static constructor from running in .NET?

You can't do this. [Static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) will be invoked before any instance of the type is created or any static member is referenced. It's called by the CLR and you have absolutely no control over the exact timing.

So the only way to avoid calling the static constructor is to never reference and using the type that contains this static constructor. Why would you define a static constructor in the first place if you don't want it to be executed? Putting an `Environment.Exit(0)` instruction into a static constructor is like taking a gun and shooting yourself into the leg.

Comment: I want loading a assembly that have a static constructor that prevent it to be loaded by other programs. Also i see some codes in SSCLI that it controlled by a ClassInit Flag so I believed that there should be some weird way to stop it.

Comment: Assemblies don't have static constructors. Types do.

Comment: there's module constructor and i think that should be static

Comment: Actually i am making a interpreter of .net, so i have to control everything in the assembly to prevent clr to execute it. If i can't stop static constructor from running, then it will run twice.

Comment: @Kii: I think you have an architect-designing problem. Not a C# one.

Comment: I think that it is related to .NET CLR so i removed C# tag...
And i am loading the assembly using reflection so i can't modify it...

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, if you load the type, the static constructor will run. There's no way around it.

You can use Cecil or MS CCI. Both of them allow you to inspect a type without loading it. You can create a dynamic type by cloning class A, and remove the static constructor and finally create the modified type.